# How to check what apps in Dock have badges?

Tags: swift, macos, macos-big-sur, badge, dock

I want to check if an app (not just mine - any app) in Dock has a badge.

Is there any chance to get it from [NSWorkspace -> runningApplications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1534059-runningapplications)?

[image]

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: I would be surprised if the accessibility API didn't expose this.

Comment: Is there any other way of retrieving info about other apps' badges? For an example, I've seen it in [Pock](https://pock.dev/)'s Dock plugin but I wasn't unable to find details about it.

Comment: @mszan In the past, if I got really stuck, I'll just DM or e-mail the devs of apps that do things I'm trying to emulate, to ask them what APIs they used. Usually they're over-the-top excited to nerd out about what they did